# Open SQL Server Express database in Red gate?

Tags: localdb, redgate

I have a SQL Server Express database that I would like to compare them to each other.

But I couldn't open them in Red Gate.

My question is: can I open SQL Server Express local db in Red Gate? (Red Gate required server name but I haven't)

Comment: Of course you can, usually the server name is: (localdb)\v11.0

Comment: **WHAT** do you mean by "Red Gate" - this is a **company** - not a single tool. Please specify **which tool** made by Red Gate you're talking about here!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Red-Gate's SQL Compare. 
If so, here is an official list of what SQL Server versions they officially support:
[Supported Versions](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC11/Requirements)

I would think you should be able to compare SQL Server Express editions, though for an official word, I would open a ticket with Red Gate Support.
Good luck!